# ajax json request problem: alert is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my jquery ajax code

```
   $.ajax({  
        url:"update.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{id:id, text:text, column_name:column_name},  
    dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){  

                 alert("HelloJson");


                }
```

My update.php page only contains

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
```

When I change dataType to text , alert HelloJson is working but when I change dataType to 'json' alert HelloJson is not working.I want to use json and How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you post also php code please?

Comment: my php page is contain just header('Content-Type:application/json');

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works as expected:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url:"update.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{id:"8", text:"code", column_name:"name"},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){

                        alert("HelloJson");
                        console.log(data);


                    },error:function(xhr,status,error){
                    console.log(error)
                }

            });
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Post data</button>

</body>
</html>
```

update.php:

```
header("Content-type:application/json");

echo json_encode(["id"=>$_POST["id"],
              "text"=>$_POST["text"],
              "column_name"=>$_POST["column_name"]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

when using `dataType: 'json'` jQuery will `parse` the response to JSON and because you dont have any content in the response you will get the error below, see it in console.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

to be valid json response it need to send at least empty quotes `""`

```
<?php
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo '""';
?>
```

Comment: I am getting this error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Comment: it could be  there is unnecessary `<` in your php, try open `update.php` in address bar

Comment: I guess you're not running it in server or `http://` protocol but  `file:///` right? try change the `update.php` with only content `""`